# Using mutiple versions of jquery in a SPA using durandal

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal

I am a working on a SPA using durandal and knockout and require. However I have a script that is reliant on the jquery-latest.js which I read should no-longer be used. However jquery-1.4.2.js seems to work fine for my script as tested outside the SPA environment but I also use 1.9.1 for most of the stuff in my SPA. Is there a way to use both versions? How will I reference them in the main.js: Currently I have been doing:

```
    'text'              : '../scripts/text',
    'durandal'          : '../scripts/durandal',
    'plugins'           : '../scripts/durandal/plugins',
    'transitions'       : '../scripts/durandal/transitions',
    'ko'                : '../scripts/knockout-3.1.0.debug',
    'jquery-latest'     : '../scripts/jquery-latest',//try-not allowed/want 1.4.2 instead
    'jquery'            : '../scripts/jquery-1.9.1',
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: jquery-latest is just the latest version of jquery. Are you sure it won't work with 1.9.1? I think durandal should work with the latest jquery. Just upgrade jquery-1.9.1 to jquery-1.11.2

Comment: @Wayne Ellery  thanks for your response. I have tried your suggestion and still not coming right. Is there a way to reference both 1.9.1 and 1.4.2?

Comment: Why doesn't what you have tried work above? I would have thought that it would have worked.

Comment: IIRC jQuery sets up a global variable $ or jQuery.  wont both version of jQuery be trying to use that? and i imagine the last one to register will win.  I think you will need to redefine one of them to something else.  or update your script to be compatible with a single version.

Comment: thanks for the responses but I ended up "recreating" my app and used jquery-1.11.2. It was a mission but seems like the cleaner way to deal with  my situation

Answer (score 0):

try this out. This will include all the dependencies on the first page load and u wil b able to use each of them. And name it as BundleConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace NameXyz
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);

        bundles.Add(
          new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/toastr.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/Q.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/breeze.debug.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/moment.js")
          );

        bundles.Add(
          new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
            .Include("~/Content/durandal.css")
            .Include("~/Content/toastr.css")
            .Include("~/Content/app.css")
          );
    }

    public static void AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(IgnoreList ignoreList)
    {
        if (ignoreList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ignoreList");
        }

        ignoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");

        //ignoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
        //ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.js", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
        //ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.css", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
    }
}
```

}

Now Go to Global.asax if not there create it

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace NameXyz
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```